# SailsJS Session not working over sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, sails.js

Here is my problem,

```
UserController.login{
req.session.isAuthenticated = true
}
```

...

```
UserController.isOnline{
     if(request.session.isAuthenticated){ //Expecting true for already logged in users
     }
...
}
```

Above condition is passing for Http requests. But, failing for Socket requests.

Anyone know how to fix this and access sessions via sockets in sailjs?

FYI,
Working on SaillJS v0.11.0
i can see htppOnly: true in request.session object

Comment: you should use policies also, I think this will work with any request, but I'm not 100% sure

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Policies